# UITableView change style

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, storyboard

I have a uitableView with different sections and rows that I created them programmatically

when I cleck on one row I will go to the new views and in new views in navigation bar I have canel button 
 with cancel button it should work like a back button but when I click on cancel it load the table but change the table style from group to plain

Thanks in Advance!

does any one know why?

would you please help me 
I want to know why it changes.
what should I add to have the same stype

here is my code:

in first table, I added the style both programmatically and via storyboard

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
style = UITableViewStyleGrouped;
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    monthTitle = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
return self;
}
```

button code

```
-(void)cancelItem{
Report *report = [[Report alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:report animated:YES];
[self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

**Edit**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
_selectedIndex = indexPath.section;
[self.tableView reloadData];
switch (indexPath.section){
    case 0:
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"WorkTime" sender:self];
```

Comment: how do you display the second table?

Comment: @janusfidel - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    _selectedIndex = indexPath.section;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    switch (indexPath.section){
        case 0:
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"WorkTime" sender:self];

Comment: @janusfidel I added as edit above

Comment: Are you using navigation controller to push on new view ???

Answer (score -1):

We can set the style as

```
[[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

Comment: `This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.` 1)the question was about `UITableView`, not `UITableViewController`; 2)even with `UITableViewController` you don't set style - you just create a new one